# Static property won't stay set?

Tags: c#

I want to share a property between two projects in the same solution, so I created a simple static class in a separate (third) project with a static property.  However, when I set it in one project, the change doesn't seem to occur when I try to get the value of the property from the other project.

Since the property is static shouldn't there only be one instance of it?  I've debugged and the value is indeed set after the assignment statement, why doesn't this apply when its referenced in the other project?
Here's the code:

```
    namespace Shared
    {
        public static class Shared
        {
           public static string old { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

Assignment statement in first project

```
   Shared.Shared.old = messageData.Items[0].DateTime;
```

Trying to access property in 2nd project

```
    if (messageData.Items[0].DateTime.CompareTo(Shared.Shared.old) > 0)
```

Comment: Are both projects accessing the value running in the same process, or are they separate applications?

Comment: Check how many copies are loaded in Debug, Modules.

Comment: Are you using your binaries in the same process? If not, they should not give back the same info.

Comment: Static properties are static in the same AppDomain. Could you share some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A static property has *one instance per process* (technically, per `AppDomain`).  If you're trying to share it between two executables, each process will get a unique value.

If you want to communicate between two executables, you'll need to use some form of Interprocess Communication, or serialize to some external source (the file system, a database, etc).

Comment: Ah, well that would explain it.  Yes, one of the projects is for a background task so it'd run in a different process.  Is there anyway to share data between them?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Yeah - it's typically just confusing to newer devs, but I also don't want to be incorrect in there...

Comment: @Orch WCF is really nice for this, but it takes a bit to setup and learn. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx  That being said, it's VERY feature rich, and makes the communication very nice.

Comment: Alright, I'm using a  WCF service already and I could do this through that, I was just hoping there'd be a way too keep this part of the code out of WCF as it would just simplify things for me.  Anyway, thanks for the responses everyone.

Comment: @Orch A simple named pipe WCF service can be done very quick and easy and self host in one of the two applications.